# Snowflake Snowpark Functions Python - Length

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm starting first steps on Snowpark for Python.
I'm not getting how to use snowflake.snowpark functions for a simple query.
What I'm trying to achieve it to have a DataFrame with:
**Length on 2 Columns (min. and max)**

This is one way that I've tried

```
# Select Specific Cols and Some Operations
df = df.select(
    max(len("BUSINESS_NAME")),
    max(len("CNPJ"))
)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
[image]

Answer (score 0):

that's not the correct syntax to create a DF from a SQL query. If you read the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/working-with-dataframes#label-snowpark-python-dataframe-construct) it gives examples for how to create DFs using different methods and, using SQL queries, it says:

### To create a DataFrame to hold the results of a SQL query, call the sql method:

```
# Create a DataFrame from a SQL query
df_sql = session.sql("SELECT name from sample_product_data")
df_sql.show()
```